# send php array through jquery ajax with index and recieve the array value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i am working on online exam test where childArray[] contains data from each row of table and parrentArray[] contains number of childArray[]. i want to get value of each childArray from ParentArray with Index passed through ajax.

```
<?php 
 $childArray1[]=[1,question,optionA,optionB,optionC];
 $childArray2[]=[1,question,optionA,optionB,optionC];
 $parentArray[]=[$childArray1,$childArray2];
?>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var counter=0;
    $("#ButtonNext").click(function(){
       $.ajax({
           type:"POST",
           url: "ChangeQuestionProcess.php",
           data:{
               MainList:"<?php echo json_encode($parentArray); ?>",
               Counter:counter,
           }, 
           success: function(result){
            $("#callMe").html(result);
        }});
        counter++;
     });
   });
</script>
```

### ChangeQuestionProcess.php

```
<?php
  $index=$_POST["Counter"]; 
  $test[]=$_POST["MainList"];
  echo test[$index];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `ChangeQuestionProcess.php`, this line:

`$test[]=$_POST["MainList"];`

...is saying "take the contents of `$_POST["MainList"]` and make it the next element of the array `$test`"

You're doing a similar thing at the top of your first script - I think you mean this, without the [] after the variable names:

```
<?php  
  $childArray1=[1,'Question 1','Option 1A','option 1B','option 1C'];
  $childArray2=[2,'Question 2','Option 2A','option 2B','option 2C'];
  $parentArray=[$childArray1,$childArray2];
?>
```

You could even simplify this to:

```
<?php
  $parentArray = [
    [1,'Question 1','Option 1A','option 1B','option 1C'],
    [2,'Question 2','Option 2A','option 2B','option 2C']
  ];
?>
```

Now back to `ChangeQuestionProcess.php` again - bear in mind that `$_POST["MainList"]` is going to be a `string` containing JSON-encoded data (as that's what `json_encode()` returns)

Therefore what I *think* you are trying to do is read the array of JSON-*decoded* data into `$test`, which you would do like so:

`$test = json_decode( $_POST["MainList"] );`

Finally, you're missing a $ when echoing your variable. But as `$test[$index]` is an array, you'll just see `Array` on your screen instead of its contents. I think you need something like [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) instead of `echo`:

```
<?php
  $index = $_POST["Counter"]; 
  $test = json_decode( $_POST["MainList"] );
  print_r( $test[$index] );
?>
```

Comment: Function `json_decode`, by default, decodes JSON string into object (`stdClass`). In order to get an `array` you need to pass `true` as a second argument: `json_decode( $_POST["MainList"], true)`

Comment: @JovanPerovic Not in this case, as the arrays are all 0-based & incrementally indexed. `json_encode()` has to convert _associative_ arrays to objects (as JSON doesn't support them) but in this instance the second `json_decode()` parameter is not required, as no associative arrays / objects were encoded.

Comment: Ouh, ok, makes sense... :)